# Java 7 applet self signed certificates

Tags: java, security, applet, self-signed

I've been trying to adopt myself and my applet to the new security constraints imposed in Java 7.

My applet is self signed and as such, it was automatically blocked. After adding the site to the exception list in the java configuration console I managed accessing it but not without having to see that annoying message shouting at me that the signer is UNKNOWN, requiring me to approve running the applet.

This one is really annoying as it requires my approval each time I try to load the applet...not storing my previous approval...

so, I found [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/self_signed_certificates_for_a) document which should have solved all my problems as the distribution of my applet is within a known community. I followed all the guidelines, created the certificate and entered it into the store that is used by the JRE (I also see that certificate from the configuration console) but the annoying approval message keeps popping and saying that the signer is still UNKNOWN...

any idea, what I'm missing? it looks like the addition of the certificate into my store had no impact on the flow whatsoever...

thanks in advance.
GBa.

Comment: Did you sign the jar(s) with the new 'known' certificate?   Also, some of the behavior is driven by the Security Level - found in the Control Panel -> Java (for windows).  High, which is the default, is set to block unsigned and self-signed.  If signing the jars doesn't work, you could try reducing the Security Level slider to Medium.

Comment: I changed it to medium because otherwise the applet will be automatically blocked without giving me an option to authorize it. I obviously signed the jars with that same key... I also verified it by using jarsigner.exe -verify -certs -verbose on all jars

Comment: Anything in the Java console log that might help?  Also did you update the manifest.mf to match what is now expected in J7 Update51?

Comment: Nothing special that I noticed in the Java console, also good point about the manifest... I forgot to mention that I added the must have property (permissions). I did choose not to add the others which are only recommended... can that be the issue, I suppose that recommendation should not affect the behavior that drastically should it?

Comment: No, we updated our JNLP applications with the permissions and codebase * but not the 3rd parm (slips my mind right now).  You also include the permission parm in the applet tag?

Comment: So, the java applet that you are attempting to run is signed with the same certificate that you exported, and you are running it on the same machine that you imported the certificate to?

Comment: Wow, Mikemil you nailed it! it turns out that I missed the necessity to add this parameter to the applet tag...the description is a bit tricky because it may sound as if it is not needed...e.g. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#PERMISSIONS)-this one is the important line `If this parameter is omitted, default is assumed. If the parameter is present and not set to default, the value must match the value of the Permissions attribute in the manifest for any JAR file that has the Permissions attribute, otherwise the applet is blocked.`

Comment: By the way, it turns out that I wasn't a complete moron when assuming that the permission tag is not required for the applet definition - see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html) look for at the last sentence... this contradicts the instructions given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#PERMISSIONS)....both given by Oracle...

Comment: well, adding the permissions=all-permissions did not solve the issue. I'm still presented with the annoying prompt upon each login to the applet... your kind help is very much appreciated. Thanks, GBa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found the problem...

It turns out that once I cloned the trusted.certs (deployment.user.security.trusted.certs) file into trusted.cacerts (deployment.user.security.trusted.cacerts) file, everything started working...

I do not understand what the difference is between the two stores, futhermore, in the link that I added in the question ([this](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/self_signed_certificates_for_a)), it talks about the certs file for individual usage and so... it made sense to me that it should work... however, it turns out that Java thinks differently :-)

anyways... this is the answer.

thanks everyone for your collaboration,
GBa.

Comment: The cacerts are the certificates belonging to verisign and such. I think you've simply declared yourself to be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately mentioned certificate fields are not provided so maybe my guess is wrong but I would suggest that you create a certificate where the Common Name in the Subject field matches the signing authority address. There are three ways to have a match and eventually avoid the warning: 
1. The host name (in the address bar) exactly matches the Common Name in the certificate's Subject. 
2. The host name matches a wildcard common name. For example, www.example.com matches the common name *.example.com. 
3. The host name is listed in the Subject Alternative Name field. 
The most common form of SSL name matching is for the SSL client to compare the server name it connected to with the common name in the server's certificate. 
If an SSL certificate has a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) field, then SSL clients are supposed to ignore the common name value and seek a match in the SAN list.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that I need to supply a certificate that matches the hostname in the address bar. This will break the ability to perform tests over certificates since they are tested in dev env. which does not sit on the same hostname as the deployment. The Java keytool asks several questions, [here's](http://www.digicert.com/code-signing/java-code-signing-guide.htm) a guide that explains what to answer (it never mentions anything about hostname)

Comment: No. The Codebase attribute in the jar manifest can be used to restrict the jar for use on a certain hostname. But the hostname need not match the signer's name.